# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError when using lwjgl with gradle

Tags: java, gradle, lwjgl

I'm trying to use Gradle with LWJGL 3, but I'm having a problem when building. The `build.gradle` file contains the following:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = "HelloWorld"
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
}
project.ext.lwjglVersion = "3.0.0a"
dependencies {
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl:${lwjglVersion}"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-windows"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-linux"
    compile "org.lwjgl:lwjgl-platform:${lwjglVersion}:natives-osx"
}
```

When I run `gradle run` I get the following output:

```
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:runjava.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1857)
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1119)
        at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.loadLibrarySystem(LWJGLUtil.java:337)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:36)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:33)
        at org.lwjgl.LWJGLUtil.initialize(LWJGLUtil.java:309)
        at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.<clinit>(MemoryUtil.java:35)
        at org.lwjgl.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
        at org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer.<init>(PointerBuffer.java:24)
        at org.lwjgl.PointerBuffer.allocateDirect(PointerBuffer.java:281)
        at org.lwjgl.BufferUtils.createPointerBuffer(BufferUtils.java:190)
        at org.lwjgl.system.libffi.Closure.<clinit>(Closure.java:45)
        at org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks.errorCallbackPrint(Callbacks.java:129)
        at HelloWorld.<clinit>(HelloWorld.java:29)
Exception in thread "main"  FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

The `HelloWorld.java` contains the following (example code from a tutorial):

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import org.lwjgl.BufferUtils;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.Callbacks;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWErrorCallback;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWKeyCallback;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.GLContext;
import org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFWvidmode;

import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryUtil.NULL;

public class HelloWorld {
    private static GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback
            = Callbacks.errorCallbackPrint(System.err);

    private static GLFWKeyCallback keyCallback = new GLFWKeyCallback() {

        @Override
        public void invoke(long window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods) {
            if (key == GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
                glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, GL_TRUE);
            }
        }
    };
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long window;

        /* Set the error callback */
        glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);

        /* Initialize GLFW */
        if (glfwInit() != GL_TRUE) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to initialize GLFW");
        }

        /* Create window */
        window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Simple example", NULL, NULL);
        if (window == NULL) {
            glfwTerminate();
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create the GLFW window");
        }

        /* Center the window on screen */
        ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(glfwGetPrimaryMonitor());
        glfwSetWindowPos(window,
                (GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode) - 640) / 2,
                (GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode) - 480) / 2
        );

        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        GLContext.createFromCurrent();
        glfwSwapInterval(1);

        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, keyCallback);
        IntBuffer width = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        IntBuffer height = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(1);
        while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) != GL_TRUE) {
            float ratio;
            glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, width, height);
            ratio = width.get() / (float) height.get();
            width.rewind();
            height.rewind();
            glViewport(0, 0, width.get(), height.get());
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glOrtho(-ratio, ratio, -1f, 1f, 1f, -1f);
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity();
            glRotatef((float) glfwGetTime() * 50f, 0f, 0f, 1f);
            glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
            glColor3f(1f, 0f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(-0.6f, -0.4f, 0f);
            glColor3f(0f, 1f, 0f);
            glVertex3f(0.6f, -0.4f, 0f);
            glColor3f(0f, 0f, 1f);
            glVertex3f(0f, 0.6f, 0f);
            glEnd();
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
            width.flip();
            height.flip();
        }
        glfwDestroyWindow(window);
        keyCallback.release();
        glfwTerminate();
        errorCallback.release();
    }
}
```

What is causing the error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As you probably already noticed, in the lwjgl folder that you downloaded(the one with the jar file), there should be a directory with the name "native". In this directory there should be three subfolders with system names(windows, macos...). This native folder should be in a folder inside you project(I created one named lwjgl). Then, in the first line of your program, you write `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "./lwjgl")`. This line tells java to search all native files there.

Comment: This won't work, you have to specify the name of the property you want to set: `System.setProperty("java.library.path", "./lwjgl/native/")`.

Comment: I didn't download an LWJGL folder. I'm using Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

You must link the native libraries of Lwjgl to your application during runtime. Thanks to gradle, the native libraries are in the classpath... somewhere.

You could go ahead and find them, extract them to a temporary location and then link them but there's already an [example project](https://github.com/badlogic/lwjgl3-maven-gradle) doing it for you.

All you need to do is to include their class `SharedLibraryLoader` to your project and call the `load()` method.

In case of this link dying, here's the full content of the class you need:

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright 2011 See AUTHORS file.
 * 
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 * 
 *   http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 * 
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 ******************************************************************************/

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.zip.CRC32;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipFile;

/** Loads shared libraries from JAR files. Call {@link SharedLibraryLoader#load() to load the
 * required LWJGL 3 native shared libraries.
 * @author mzechner
 * @author Nathan Sweet */
public class SharedLibraryLoader {
    static public boolean isWindows = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows");
    static public boolean isLinux = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Linux");
    static public boolean isMac = System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Mac");
    static public boolean isIos = false;
    static public boolean isAndroid = false;
    static public boolean isARM = System.getProperty("os.arch").startsWith("arm");
    static public boolean is64Bit = System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("amd64")
        || System.getProperty("os.arch").equals("x86_64");

    // JDK 8 only.
    static public String abi = (System.getProperty("sun.arch.abi") != null ? System.getProperty("sun.arch.abi") : "");

    static {
        String vm = System.getProperty("java.runtime.name");
        if (vm != null && vm.contains("Android Runtime")) {
            isAndroid = true;
            isWindows = false;
            isLinux = false;
            isMac = false;
            is64Bit = false;
        }
        if (!isAndroid && !isWindows && !isLinux && !isMac) {
            isIos = true;
            is64Bit = false;
        }
    }

    static boolean load = true;

    static {
        // Don't extract natives if using JWS.
        try {
            Method method = Class.forName("javax.jnlp.ServiceManager").getDeclaredMethod("lookup", new Class[] {String.class});
            method.invoke(null, "javax.jnlp.PersistenceService");
            load = false;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            load = true;
        }   
    }

    /** Extracts the LWJGL native libraries from the classpath and sets the "org.lwjgl.librarypath" system property. */
    static public synchronized void load () {
        load(false);
    }

    /** Extracts the LWJGL native libraries from the classpath and sets the "org.lwjgl.librarypath" system property. */
    static public synchronized void load (boolean disableOpenAL) {      
        if (!load) return;

        SharedLibraryLoader loader = new SharedLibraryLoader();
        File nativesDir = null;
        try {
            if (SharedLibraryLoader.isWindows) {
                nativesDir = loader.extractFile(SharedLibraryLoader.is64Bit ? "lwjgl.dll" : "lwjgl32.dll", null).getParentFile();
                if (!disableOpenAL)
                    loader.extractFile(SharedLibraryLoader.is64Bit ? "OpenAL.dll" : "OpenAL32.dll", nativesDir.getName());
            } else if (SharedLibraryLoader.isMac) {
                nativesDir = loader.extractFile("liblwjgl.dylib", null).getParentFile();
                if (!disableOpenAL) loader.extractFile("libopenal.dylib", nativesDir.getName());
            } else if (SharedLibraryLoader.isLinux) {
                nativesDir = loader.extractFile(SharedLibraryLoader.is64Bit ? "liblwjgl.so" : "liblwjgl32.so", null).getParentFile();
                if (!disableOpenAL)
                    loader.extractFile(SharedLibraryLoader.is64Bit ? "libopenal.so" : "libopenal32.so", nativesDir.getName());
            }
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to extract LWJGL natives.", ex);
        }
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", nativesDir.getAbsolutePath());
        load = false;
    }

    static private final HashSet<String> loadedLibraries = new HashSet<String>();

    private String nativesJar;

    public SharedLibraryLoader () {
    }

    /** Fetches the natives from the given natives jar file. Used for testing a shared lib on the fly.
     * @param nativesJar */
    public SharedLibraryLoader (String nativesJar) {
        this.nativesJar = nativesJar;
    }

    /** Returns a CRC of the remaining bytes in the stream. */
    public String crc (InputStream input) {
        if (input == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("input cannot be null.");
        CRC32 crc = new CRC32();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        try {
            while (true) {
                int length = input.read(buffer);
                if (length == -1) break;
                crc.update(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            if(input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
        return Long.toString(crc.getValue(), 16);
    }

    /** Maps a platform independent library name to a platform dependent name. */
    public String mapLibraryName (String libraryName) {
        if (isWindows) return libraryName + (is64Bit ? "64.dll" : ".dll");
        if (isLinux) return "lib" + libraryName + (isARM ? "arm" + abi : "") + (is64Bit ? "64.so" : ".so");
        if (isMac) return "lib" + libraryName + (is64Bit ? "64.dylib" : ".dylib");
        return libraryName;
    }

    /** Loads a shared library for the platform the application is running on.
     * @param libraryName The platform independent library name. If not contain a prefix (eg lib) or suffix (eg .dll). */
    public synchronized void load (String libraryName) {
        // in case of iOS, things have been linked statically to the executable, bail out.
        if (isIos) return;

        libraryName = mapLibraryName(libraryName);
        if (loadedLibraries.contains(libraryName)) return;

        try {
            if (isAndroid)
                System.loadLibrary(libraryName);
            else
                loadFile(libraryName);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't load shared library '" + libraryName + "' for target: "
                + System.getProperty("os.name") + (is64Bit ? ", 64-bit" : ", 32-bit"), ex);
        }
        loadedLibraries.add(libraryName);
    }

    private InputStream readFile (String path) {
        if (nativesJar == null) {
            InputStream input = SharedLibraryLoader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + path);
            if (input == null) throw new RuntimeException("Unable to read file for extraction: " + path);
            return input;
        }

        // Read from JAR.
        ZipFile file = null;
        try {
            file = new ZipFile(nativesJar);
            ZipEntry entry = file.getEntry(path);
            if (entry == null) throw new RuntimeException("Couldn't find '" + path + "' in JAR: " + nativesJar);
            return file.getInputStream(entry);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading '" + path + "' in JAR: " + nativesJar, ex);
        } finally {
            if(file != null) {
                try {
                    file.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    /** Extracts the specified file into the temp directory if it does not already exist or the CRC does not match. If file
     * extraction fails and the file exists at java.library.path, that file is returned.
     * @param sourcePath The file to extract from the classpath or JAR.
     * @param dirName The name of the subdirectory where the file will be extracted. If null, the file's CRC will be used.
     * @return The extracted file. */
    public File extractFile (String sourcePath, String dirName) throws IOException {
        try {
            String sourceCrc = crc(readFile(sourcePath));
            if (dirName == null) dirName = sourceCrc;

            File extractedFile = getExtractedFile(dirName, new File(sourcePath).getName());
            return extractFile(sourcePath, sourceCrc, extractedFile);
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // Fallback to file at java.library.path location, eg for applets.
            File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.library.path"), sourcePath);
            if (file.exists()) return file;
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    /** Returns a path to a file that can be written. Tries multiple locations and verifies writing succeeds. */
    private File getExtractedFile (String dirName, String fileName) {
        // Temp directory with username in path.
        File idealFile = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/libgdx" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "/"
            + dirName, fileName);
        if (canWrite(idealFile)) return idealFile;

        // System provided temp directory.
        try {
            File file = File.createTempFile(dirName, null);
            if (file.delete()) {
                file = new File(file, fileName);
                if (canWrite(file)) return file;
            }
        } catch (IOException ignored) {
        }

        // User home.
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.libgdx/" + dirName, fileName);
        if (canWrite(file)) return file;

        // Relative directory.
        file = new File(".temp/" + dirName, fileName);
        if (canWrite(file)) return file;

        return idealFile; // Will likely fail, but we did our best.
    }

    /** Returns true if the parent directories of the file can be created and the file can be written. */
    private boolean canWrite (File file) {
        File parent = file.getParentFile();
        File testFile;
        if (file.exists()) {
            if (!file.canWrite() || !canExecute(file)) return false;
            // Don't overwrite existing file just to check if we can write to directory.
            testFile = new File(parent, UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        } else {
            parent.mkdirs();
            if (!parent.isDirectory()) return false;
            testFile = file;
        }
        try {
            new FileOutputStream(testFile).close();
            if (!canExecute(testFile)) return false;
            return true;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            return false;
        } finally {
            testFile.delete();
        }
    }

    private boolean canExecute (File file) {
        try {
            Method canExecute = File.class.getMethod("canExecute");
            if ((Boolean)canExecute.invoke(file)) return true;

            Method setExecutable = File.class.getMethod("setExecutable", boolean.class, boolean.class);
            setExecutable.invoke(file, true, false);

            return (Boolean)canExecute.invoke(file);
        } catch (Exception ignored) {
        }
        return false;
    }

    private File extractFile (String sourcePath, String sourceCrc, File extractedFile) throws IOException {
        String extractedCrc = null;
        if (extractedFile.exists()) {
            try {
                extractedCrc = crc(new FileInputStream(extractedFile));
            } catch (FileNotFoundException ignored) {
            }
        }

        // If file doesn't exist or the CRC doesn't match, extract it to the temp dir.
        if (extractedCrc == null || !extractedCrc.equals(sourceCrc)) {
            try {
                InputStream input = readFile(sourcePath);
                extractedFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(extractedFile);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                while (true) {
                    int length = input.read(buffer);
                    if (length == -1) break;
                    output.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
                input.close();
                output.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Error extracting file: " + sourcePath + "\nTo: " + extractedFile.getAbsolutePath(), ex);
            }
        }

        return extractedFile;
    }

    /** Extracts the source file and calls System.load. Attemps to extract and load from multiple locations. Throws runtime
     * exception if all fail. */
    private void loadFile (String sourcePath) {
        String sourceCrc = crc(readFile(sourcePath));

        String fileName = new File(sourcePath).getName();

        // Temp directory with username in path.
        File file = new File(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "/libgdx" + System.getProperty("user.name") + "/" + sourceCrc,
            fileName);
        Throwable ex = loadFile(sourcePath, sourceCrc, file);
        if (ex == null) return;

        // System provided temp directory.
        try {
            file = File.createTempFile(sourceCrc, null);
            if (file.delete() && loadFile(sourcePath, sourceCrc, file) == null) return;
        } catch (Throwable ignored) {
        }

        // User home.
        file = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/.libgdx/" + sourceCrc, fileName);
        if (loadFile(sourcePath, sourceCrc, file) == null) return;

        // Relative directory.
        file = new File(".temp/" + sourceCrc, fileName);
        if (loadFile(sourcePath, sourceCrc, file) == null) return;

        // Fallback to java.library.path location, eg for applets.
        file = new File(System.getProperty("java.library.path"), sourcePath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            System.load(file.getAbsolutePath());
            return;
        }

        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    /** @return null if the file was extracted and loaded. */
    private Throwable loadFile (String sourcePath, String sourceCrc, File extractedFile) {
        try {
            System.load(extractFile(sourcePath, sourceCrc, extractedFile).getAbsolutePath());
            return null;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return ex;
        }
    }
}
```

This example project works with Lwjgl 3 (as OP requested). However, if you are using Lwjgl 2.9.x it still works you just need to change the name of the libraries in the `load` method.

Answer (score -3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html):

> Thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

So, given the `no lwjgl in java.library.path`, it can't find the native library for some reason. Sorry, no gradle experience to help you there...